# QMessage Box with QlineEdit with AutoAlignment

Tags: qt, qt4

I have added QLineEdit but the Problem is that i am not able to align them properly in QMessageBox is there any way to align them automatically in a suitable manner ?

I have done it with these codes:

```
frame_No.setFixedSize(150, 20); 
frame_No.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
```

(Frame_No is my lineedit )

Comment: Could you please provide more information, maybe the parts of code about how you do that?

Comment: I have done it with These ....


 
frame_No.setFixedSize(150, 20);
frame_No.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);

Comment: Frame_No is my lineedit

Comment: Please use **edit** to update your post. You may find it below tags.

Comment: Excuse me, which do you want to align? The **QLineEdit itself**? Or the **input text** inside QLineEdit?

Comment: QLineEdit itself on QMessage Box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QMessageBox with QLineEdit? Is [a QInputDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qinputdialog.html) maybe what you are looking for?

Comment: Actually first i want to check the condition with Yes and No from user if user go for Yes then i Need to give two line Edits so that i can get value from user from line Edits ? i have implemented with Qmessage box with selection but i am not able to get the value from user ...

Comment: The Problem was that i have added line Edits but i am not able to allign them properly?

Comment: I have done it with These ....


 
frame_No.setFixedSize(150, 20);
frame_No.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);

Comment: Well for such a task a full Dialog would maybe better then. I use only the static methods of QMessageBox and create QDialogs for tasks which require more input

Comment: A QDialog can have as many inputs as you like. Qt comes with a program called QDesigner which lets you create QDialogs (among others) with all their inputs which you can implement in your application

Comment: But how to use it like we can use QMessageBox as Critical ... but how to use it as critical so that User will Need to put the data first into Dialog ... and then the program will run ....

Comment: If you want such a behaviour you have to write the code yourself. Create the class for the QDialog and maybe give it a static method so you can call `MyQDialog::getValue`

Comment: actually the Thing which i want to do is to get some data in line Edits and want to Exit to the same code where it was being executed .... so that i can process this data ....

Comment: Yes and for that you have to create a static method in that dialog you can call as I stated above